# rsync mkstemp failed Invalid argument (22) with davfs mount of Box.com cloud

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, dropbox, cloud, davfs2

I mounted Box.com cloud storage using davfs according to [these instructions](http://xmodulo.com/2013/02/how-to-mount-box-com-cloud-storage-on-linux.html). I mounted my Box.com account under /home/me/Cloud/Box

I can access the mounted filesystem via Dolphin as well as via the terminal. It is a little slow, but I can list (ls) and navigate the entire directory structure with no errors.

Next I attempted to run rsync as follows:

```
rsync -auvz  --max-size=250M --exclude '.*' /home/me/Music/ /home/me/Cloud/Box/Music
```

I also tried:

```
rsync -auv  /home/me/Music/A /home/me/Cloud/Box/Music
```

and other variations of rsync commands. The command is copying my Music from my local file system (/home/me/Music/) to the Box cloud (/home/me/Cloud/Box/Music) via the davfs mount.

I always get a lot of errors of this form:

```
rsync: mkstemp <filename> failed: Invalid argument (22)
```

A specific example is:

```
rsync: mkstemp "/home/me/Cloud/Box/Music/VariousArtists/.01_Track_1.mp3.YVmFI9" failed: Invalid argument (22)
```

This is all happening on Kubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit, server grade hardware, with a fast/reliable cable modem connection (12 Mb/s upload speeds).

Comment: I've had situations where rsync -av would hang, and a long list of these mkstemp/"invalid argument (22)" errors would appear after I pressed Ctrl-C - though not before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem occurs because of `rsync` making temporary files with filenames that the box.com and/or davfs do not understand. Thus the file `.01_Track_1.mp3.YVmFI9` does not exist on your system, but is a temporary [artifact](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/artefact) of `rsync`. Some guesswork from my side: if you don't get the error on all files, you probably only get the errors on files that were already uploaded (and changed).

It [used to be impossible](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2002-June/002973.html) to switch off this temporary file generation, but you might nowadays have more luck by adding the option `--inplace`.
However the advantages of using rsync if you are not talking to a rsync-daemon (which you are not if you are using davfs), are unclear to me.

Therefore, as an alternative, you could try `cp --update`, which only copies a file when the source is **newer** than the destination. New files and any files with changes in ID3 tags will get copied, others will not.

Or if you need to have more control use `find`:

```
cd /home/me/Music/
find * -size -250M -print0 | cpio -pdmv0 /home/me/Cloud/Box/Music
```

this preserves the hierarchy structure and `cpio` does not overwrite existing files that are not older.

Comment: One reason for using rsync is that I already know how to limit it to copying files less than 250MB and files or directories that are not hidden. I use `--max-size=250M --exclude '.*' `. I'm sure `cp` can be made to do this... maybe by piping the output of find into cp? But I don't know how to do that yet. If we come up with a solution, I'll try `cp -ru`. Thanks

Comment: In that case you don't need cp -u at all, use cpio (see updated answer)

Comment: Thank you. I believe this will solve it for me. You educated me in the process, which I appreciate. (FYI, in my case I want files less than 250MB, not greater than.)

Comment: That is what `... -size -250M` does, otherwise you would use `+250M` (there was briefly a wrong version here, but I realised it before the edit was fixed)

Answer (score 9):

#### 1. Issues with special characters in filenames

Are there any special characters in the filenames? Depending on the filesystem you're writing these files to, they may not allow you to prefix files with a dot (`.`) for example.

#### 2. Problems with rsync modification times and webdav2

I came across this [blog post](http://www.p14nd4.com/blog/2012/08/15/box-com-rsync-problem-solved/) where an issue is described with `rsync` having a problem writing/tracking file modification times across webdav2 mounted box.com directories.

The problem shows up like this in the mounted file system:

```
david@sydney:~/Pictures$ ls -l /mnt/box/bwca/08/09/IMG_3084.CR2
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 12564061 Aug 14 16:08 /mnt/box/bwca/08/09/IMG_3084.CR2
david@sydney:~/Pictures$ ls -l 2012/08/09/IMG_3084.CR2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 12564061 Aug  9 13:00 2012/08/09/IMG_3084.CR2
```

That same article showed a workaround:

```
$ rsync -avhP --size-only --bwlimit=64 2012/08 /mnt/box/bwca/
```

This is an OK way to use `rsync`, but it's only comparing files based on their size now, not their checksums.

#### 3. Issues with davfs2 (WebDAV)

I came across this thread titled: [rsync via davfs2?](http://sourceforge.net/p/dav/discussion/82588/thread/3d544c3b) in the WebDAV (davfs) forum over on sourceforge. Someone was inquiring about a similar situation where they wanted to use WebDAV to mount an online storage provider and perform rsync's to the mounted storage via WebDAV. This is what one of the [developers (Werner Baumann) of WebDAV had to say about this topic](http://sourceforge.net/p/dav/discussion/82588/thread/3d544c3b#61dc/b1f3).

*excerpt of Werner's response*

> - davfs2 will only upload complete files. It can not do the incremental stuff rsync usually does, and that makes rsync very
>     efficient.
> - davfs2 uses a local cache on disk. This will make it more responsive and your application should profit from this too. But it needs local
>     disk space for this. You should allow for a large cache size, so rsync
>     can do most of its work with the local cache, and davfs2 will upload
>     most of the files in the background, when rsync has already finished.

*Werner goes on to suggest the following*

> This could be a disadvantage in this case. When rsync reads a file on
>   the remote host, it must be transfered by davfs2 into the local cache
>   first (if it is not already there). This could make the process really
>   and unnecessary slow. As rsync only works as a sophisticated
>   copy-program in your case, it might be better to use cp instead. cp
>   has an options (-u) to copy only files that are newer than the ones in
>   the davfs2 file system (= smartdrive) and it would not need to read
>   the files, but only reads file meta data like mtime.
>
> A command like "cp -pru directory/to/backup dav/" might do the job. It
>   shold not download files (like rsync might do, but I am not sure)
>   (please look at the manuals of cp and rsync).

#### Options?

So as @Anthon has suggested, you can use the `cp -u` method to copy the files. Realizing that this method solely looks at a file's size as a factor in comparison, so it's not completely reliable.

You should not use anything that only looks at modification times when comparing files, `cp -pru`. [Werner explains why in this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/dav/discussion/82588/thread/3d544c3b#61dc/26df):

*excerpt on issue with mod times*

> When you unmount a davfs2 file system and mount it again at some later
>   time, file times may have changed according to the time information
>   from the server. Tools like cp -pu and rsync can not rely on these
>   times to determine what files have changed.

So given the various issues surrounding modification times an approach using purely checksums seems like a better fit:

```
$ rsync -avvz --omit-dir-times --checksum --human-readable --progress <local dir> <remote dir>
```

Comment: Hi. There are no special characters in the file names. My filename on disk is simply "01_Track_1.mp3". The dot prefix is not part of the normal filename, nor is the extra extension (e.g., .mp3.YVmFI9). Also note that not every file fails. The failures don't seem to have a pattern.

Comment: is this enough info? `got file_sum
recv_files(Some_Music_[1999]/Some_Music_[1999]Zuni_SongVarious_Artists24.mp3)
rsync: mkstemp "/home/me/Cloud/Box/Music/Some_Music_[1999]/.Some_Music_[1999]Zuni_SongVarious_Artists24.mp3.1aWWRY" failed: Invalid argument (22)
got file_sum`

Comment: another example: `got file_sum
recv_files(Carlos/Dance/05-Tapestry-Carlos.mp3)
rsync: mkstemp "/home/me/Cloud/Box/Music/Carlos/Dance/.05-Tapestry-Carlos.mp3.WeGbGS" failed: Invalid argument (22)
got file_sum
recv_files(Carlos/Dance/06-Dance-Turquoise_Dance-Carlos.mp3)`

Comment: @MountainX - see if my update is your issue. Also what version of `rsync` are you using? `rsync --version`.

Comment: `rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30` and I'm testing your updated solution now. Thanks!

Comment: In my testing `cp -ru` seems faster. That's just a guess, but I think I'll go with either `cp -ru` or `find | cpio` for now. Thank you!

Comment: @MountainX - if you're interested, I've updated w/ additional info and a alternative.

Comment: your answer is extremely interesting and informative. Thank you for the great updates. In this case I'm going to go with `cp -ru` because I'm dealing mostly with MP3's. I will rarely be modifying them, and then it will only be the ID3 tags. In my testing last night `cp` was faster than `rsync`. Your answer explains why.

Comment: Yup, I just wanted to put the why behind your question. Glad it's working out for you.

Answer (score 5):

To stop the `Invalid argument (22)` error I had to stop rsync from creating its temp files on the davfs destination.

```
rsync --temp-dir=/tmp
```

I think what happens is rsync's temp file names start with `.` and davfs does not allow this.  So I went further and told rsync to ignore source files with names starting with `.`.  Since I'm using `--delete`, I also told it not to try to delete the `lost+found` directory in the davfs destination.

```
rsync --temp-dir=/tmp --exclude lost+found --exclude '.*'
```

Comment: I encountered this issue on Cygwin and this question was the top search engine hit. The accepted answer did not work for me as I was working on a remote file synchronisation across the internet so using rsync was mandatory. The --temp-dir suggestion in this answer was the solution for me.